# I tried to install node previous version run the angular app, the error persists, help me in resolving this..?

Tags: angular, npm, ng

`

```js
{
  "name": "magicfilm",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "server": "json-server --watch src/api/db.json --port 3000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.16.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "^5.13.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.8.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1398.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "boxicons": "^2.1.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-calendar": "^4.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
    "react-s3": "^1.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.63.4",
    "server": "^1.0.38",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.6",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

`Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap : es2015 as esm2015

- Generating browser application bundles...(node:20108) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
  (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
  \ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:internal/crypto/hash:69
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
at E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
at E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19
at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:48:13)
at processResource (E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
at iteratePitchingLoaders (E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
at runLoaders (E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
at NormalModule.doBuild (E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
at NormalModule.build (E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
at Compilation.buildModule (E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
at E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:981:14 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.17.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! movie-project@0.0.0 ng: `ng "serve"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the movie-project@0.0.0 ng script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-18T19_58_30_781Z-debug.log
PS E:\Project\Movie-Ticket-Booking-System\MovieBookingFrontEnd>

[image]

can anyone help how to resolve this..

this is package.json file
{
"name": "magicfilm",
"private": true,
"version": "0.0.0",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"dev": "vite",
"build": "vite build",
"lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
"preview": "vite preview",
"server": "json-server --watch src/api/db.json --port 3000"
},
"dependencies": {
"@date-io/date-fns": "^2.16.0",
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
"@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.2",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
"@mui/material": "^5.13.4",
"@mui/styled-engine": "^5.13.2",
"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.8.0",
"aws-sdk": "^2.1398.0",
"axios": "^1.4.0",
"boxicons": "^2.1.4",
"date-fns": "^2.30.0",
"json-server": "^0.17.3",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-calendar": "^4.3.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-icons": "^4.9.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
"react-s3": "^1.3.1",
"sass": "^1.63.4",
"server": "^1.0.38",
"styled-components": "^5.2.1",
"sweetalert2": "^11.7.6",
"yup": "^1.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/react": "^18.0.28",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
"eslint": "^8.38.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
"vite": "^4.3.2"
}
}

I tried installing nvm, changing the node version to 12.11.1, but this error comes..

Comment: Did you try to change node version on 16 and above?

Comment: Can you also add the content of package.json in your question